# Hide SSRS parameters in CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, hide, dynamics-crm-2011

I describe my problem differently,
 I could open the report with the following code

```js
var url="/"+orgname+"/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&helpID=OppClients.rdl&id=%7bC7D34446-7F90-E111-A8F3-080027EA7FF9%7d&p:nomclient=aziza boulabyar";

window.open(url, "", "height=" + (screen.availHeight * .75)
     + ",width=" + (screen.availWidth * .75)
     + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,location=0");
```

Now I want to hide the parameter in the reports and when I added `&rc:parameters=false` to the url I get an error as described in the picture below

Can some one tell me how to solve this problem

---

Below the contents of the log File:

```
at ErrorInformation.LogError()
at ErrorInformation..ctor(Exception exception, Uri requestUrl, Boolean logError)
at MainApplication.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
at EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Une exception de type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' a été levée.
Error Message: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'rc:parameters=false' in Request.QueryString on page /Manhattan/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx
The raw request was 'GET /Manhattan/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&helpID=OppClients.rdl&id=%7bC7D34446-7F90-E111-A8F3-080027EA7FF9%7d&rc:parameters=false&p:nomclient=aziza%20boulabyar' called from .
Error Details: Une exception de type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' a été levée.
Source File: Not available
Line Number: Not available
Request URL: http://localhost:5555/Manhattan/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&helpID=OppClients.rdl&id=%7bC7D34446-7F90-E111-A8F3-080027EA7FF9%7d&rc:parameters=false&p:nomclient=aziza%20boulabyar
Stack Trace Info: [InvalidOperationException: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'rc:parameters=false' in Request.QueryString on page /Manhattan/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx
The raw request was 'GET /Manhattan/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&helpID=OppClients.rdl&id=%7bC7D34446-7F90-E111-A8F3-080027EA7FF9%7d&rc:parameters=false&p:nomclient=aziza%20boulabyar' called from .]
à Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameter(HttpRequest request, ArrayList parameterCollection, String key, String value, ParameterSources source, EntityType pageEntityType, FormAdditionalAllowedParameters additionalAllowedParameters)
à Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameters(Page page, EntityType pageEntityType, Boolean alwaysEnableParameterChecking, FormAdditionalAllowedParameters formAdditionalAllowedParametersTemp)
à Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameters(Page page, EntityType pageEntityType, Boolean alwaysEnableParameterChecking)
à Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppPage.ValidatePageParameters()
à Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException: Une exception de type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' a été levée.]
à System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
à System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
à System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: No picture attached - can you give details of the error?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample of working]

My solution involves several steps, mostly unsupported - but it works.

1. Clone the existing C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\CRMReports\viewer\viewer.aspx to .\viewerNoToolbar.aspx
2. Update in viewerNoToolbar.aspx the following code to remove the Toolbar from SSRS :-

   ```
   function reportLoaded()
   {

   if (oFrame.readyState === "complete")
   {
       addToRecent();
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   function reportLoaded()
   {

   if (oFrame.readyState === "complete")
   {
       addToRecent();
       var frameDoc = oFrame.contentDocument || oFrame.contentWindow.document; 
       var reportViewerToolbar = frameDoc.getElementById("reportViewer_Toolbar");
       reportViewerToolbar.style.display = "none";
   }
   ```
3. Insert a DIV to hide the existing CRM toolbar and move the existing resultFrame IFrame out of the DIV

   ```
   </div>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   ```

   to

   ```
   </div>
   <div style="display: none">
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   ```

   also close it off by changing the below from

   ```
        </table>
    </body>
   ```

   to (and remove the existing td block related to resultFrame)

   ```
           </table>
       </div>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
           <tr style="height: 100%;">
               <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-width: 2px;
                   border-color: #000000">
                   <div id="divResultFrame">
                       <iframe name="resultFrame" id="resultFrame" src="/_static/blank.htm" style="border: 0px;
                           margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                   </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </body>
   ```
4. Change your query to

   ```
   var url="/"+orgname+"/crmreports/viewer/viewerNoToolBar.aspx?
   ```

   and don't worry about rc:Toolbar

Good luck 
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

According to this article [Pass parameters and options with a URL in SQL Reporting Services](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/) you did right.

But when I tried to do the same I've got this error wich tells absolutely nothing.

[image: Error]

To see what's going on I would recommend you to use tracing, see this post [CrmDiagTool 2011](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/04/new-tool-crmdiagtool-2011.html), this tool will make using it much easier.
My guess is that you need to make those parameters optional somehow.

Sorry, don't have time to dive into it.
If you don't solve it in a couple days let me know we'll work it out.